# libldap_r-2.4.so.2 missing when importing python-ldap on AWS

Tags: aws-lambda, python-ldap

I just cant get python-ldap to work inside AWS-Lambda. I have a simple Lambda script:

```
import ldap

def main():
  print("Success")
```

and a Layer I built on an EC2 AmazonLinux2 (which works locally). When i test the Lambda with the layer I get an Error: "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': libldap_r-2.4.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory".

From what I can tell this is some OS file which is not present on my Layer zip file. I can find it on my EC2 instance under `/usr/lib64/libldap_r-2.4.so.2`. Has somebody encountered this error.

Comment: Did you installed the module in zip folder? like this https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-import-module-error-python/

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who's looking for the solution: Adding libraries to the final lambda zip helps:

```
find / -name libldap_r-2.4.so.2 -print0 | xargs -0 zip -jg /tmp/my_lambda.zip
```

I followed this [guide](https://medium.com/@sct10876/run-python-ldap-on-aws-lambda-131ac703f10c) to deploy the Lambda with the `python-ldap`.